# MySQL Custom WEEK() Mode

Tags: mysql, week-number

I am trying to create a weekly report (including grouping by `WEEK(date)`) where weeks start on Monday.  However, Week 1 is always the first week any day of a new year occurs.  For example if Jan 1st is a Friday, that is week one.

This doesn't seem to be consistent with MySQL mode options for WEEK():
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Based on the available options it only works if the week has 4 or more days (options 1 and 3) or the Monday is in the new year (options 5 and 7).  Neither of these account for example week 1 of 2016:

```
Wk  Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
No. 
1   28  29  30  31  1   2   3
```

Is there any way to order/number the week numbers in MySQL based on this custom week mode requirement?

Comment: what is your expected behavior?

Comment: Excepted behavior is that Week 1 is always the first week any day of a new year occurs. For example if Jan 1st is a Friday, that is week one.  The start of the week occurs on that Monday though.  In the example above, that would be week 1 of the year and the day of the week it starts is Monday.  This does not align with the options provided by MySQL

Comment: This is not so `custom`. '2015-12-28' is in week 1 of 2016 as you expect, but this is not quite `custom`

Comment: That does not appear to be the case.  `SELECT WEEK('2015-12-28', 5);`  results in `52`

Comment: As described in your comment, you mentioned `that would be week 1 of the year and the day of the week it starts is Monday`. Take 2016-01-01 week for example, its Monday for example, it is '2015-12-28'.

Comment: Correct.  So Week 1 starts on Monday, 2015-12-28.  However MySQL reports WEEK('2015-12-28') as 52, not 1.